# How to send Data from Controller to cshtml with ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, controller

I am working with a own dataBase where i want to get descriptions out of my DB and put the data into a table in html.
But i can't really find anything useful and i don't really know how to transmit the data from the controller to the view - or how to request the data from the view to the Controller.

This is how my Controller looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult getTableNames()
        {
            DatabaseItemDescription databaseItemDescription = new DatabaseItemDescription();
            databaseItemDescription.Name = "abc";
            databaseItemDescription.Description = "def";
            databaseItemDescription.Content = "ghi";

            return View(databaseItemDescription); //Does this work?
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my Index.cshtml looks like:

```
@page
@model DatabaseItemDescription

<h1>DatabaseEditTest</h1>


<table id="buttonTable">
    <thead>

    </thead>
</table>

<table id="descriptionTable"
       class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Content</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>


<script>
    function getFirstTableDesc() {
        $("#firstTable thead").remove();
        $("#buttonTable thead").append("<tr>" + "<th><button onclick='updateTableDesc()'>Update</button></td>" + "<th><button onclick='refreshTableDesc()'>Refresh</button></td>" + "<tr>");
    }

    function updateTableDesc() {
        $("#descriptionTable tbody").empty();

        //here i want to read the Data from the Controller and insert it into the table like:
        //Fetch Data from Controller
        //$("#descriptionTable tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td><button onclick='Edit()'>Edit</button></td>" + "<td>${Name}</td>" + "<td>${Description}</td>" + "<td>${Content}</td>" + "</tr>");
    }
    }

    function refreshTableDesc() {

    }
</script>
```

I would be really thankful if somebody could help me!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have a strongly-typed view in the code (with `@model` woth `m` in lowercase),

```
@model DatabaseItemDescription
```

You can use the `Model` property in a view to read information that comes from `Controller`.

> return View(databaseItemDescription); //Does this work?

You are passing this object which is the type of `DatabaseItemDescription` to your `View` as a `Model`. You can access this information my `Model`, so, you can try this:

```
<tr>
    <th> Maybe you add some links here to perform actions like edit/delete </th>
    <th>@Model.Name</th>
    <th>@Model.Description</th>
    <th>@Model.Content</th>
</tr>
```

It is just to read information from what is comming from controller and display it on the view. You can add more properties if you need.

Comment: Does this also work for a list?

Because i will have a list of like 15 entries and that's why i am confused how i insert the data in the tables

Comment: I've updated my answer. Here we are talking about how to send data from controller to view and display it. To persist, I think would be better to have another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <th>@Model.Action</th>
    <th>@Model.Name</th>
    <th>@Model.Description</th>
    <th>@Model.Content</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed the things, there are two approach you can change and make it work, if you want your view to change as @Felipe Oriani has suggested, you also need to change your Index method and return data from it as model

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        DatabaseItemDescription databaseItemDescription = new DatabaseItemDescription();
        //prepare model

        return View(databaseItemDescription);
    }
```

then you can bind using @Modal.Name, @Model.Description etc.

Other approach as you tried to get data from JS as below, get data using Ajax call and bind response

```
function updateTableDesc() {
    //here i want to read the Data from the Controller and insert it into the table like:
    //Get data using Ajax call to "Home/getTableNames" and bind using JS
}
```

And change your `getTableNames` method to return Json

```
    public IActionResult getTableNames()
    {
        DatabaseItemDescription databaseItemDescription = new DatabaseItemDescription();
        //prepare model
        return Json(databaseItemDescription); //this will work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so regarding your case there is a very good plugin called [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) that you can use to show your data on your `View` from the `Controller`. You can refer to the below code snippet for your requirement:

Your `Model`:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class DatabaseItemDescription 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your `Controller`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult getTableNames()
        {
            List<DatabaseItemDescription> databaseItemDescription = new List<DatabaseItemDescription>();

            //Example of how you could initialize your list
            databaseItemDescription.Add(new DatabaseItemDescription
            {
             Name = "abc",
             Description = "def",
             Content = "ghi"
            });

            databaseItemDescription.Add(new DatabaseItemDescription
            {
             Name = "efg",
             Description = "hij",
             Content = "klm"
            });

            return Json(databaseItemDescription, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

And your `View` would look like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    @*<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>*@

    <!-- CDN LINKS-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.3.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>DataTable Example</h1>
        <p class="lead">A project dedicated to data table example in MVC</p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <center>
        <div style="width: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px" ;>
            <table id="dataTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px" ;>Name</th>
                        <th style="width: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px" ;>Description </th>
                        <th style="width: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px" ;>Content </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "@Url.Action("getTableNames", "Home")",
                    "method": "post",
                    "dataType" : "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                            paging: true,
                            sort: true,
                            searching: true,
                            data:data,
                            columns: [
                                { 'data': 'Name'},
                                { 'data': 'Description' },
                                { 'data': 'Content' }
                            ]
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For your refreshing and update, you can refer to the official documentation of the plugin or you can create your custom buttons and bind them using `AJAX` to your `Controller` methods. I hope this helps you out.